# Restore a angular project after git checkout

Tags: node.js, angular, git, npm

I'm new to Angular development. So I have a question concerning the data that will be stored in the git repository which was created by Angular CLI: Actually I created a new Angular workspace with `ng new helloworld`. The used Angular CLI version is 7.2.1. It will be created a Git repository. In the `.gitignore` file there are a bunch of entries. So far. With the `ng new` command, it creates some other important stuff like the `node_modules` folder.

Now the question is: If I checkout this git repository I will missing the `node_modules` folder. How is the way in this matter? How can I automatically create add the necessary node modules? I guess the storage of this `node_modules` folder is not the correct way because otherwise it would not be an entry of the `.gitignore` file...

Comment: in git repo you have no need to add node_modules if you want to clone your project after cloning run command `npm i` it will add all node_modules according to your project

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The contents of node_modules is not meant to be committed to git. It just contains packages for the project as configured in the **packages.json** file. Once you checkout, go to the project directory and run

> npm install

This downloads all required files from the cloud and populates a new node_modules directory.

Comment: I tried that but this is my terminal output first lines:      > fsevents@1.2.4 install /Users/JMainol/Desktop/02-spa/node_modules/fsevents
> node install

node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://fsevents-binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1.2.4/fse-v1.2.4-node-v72-darwin-x64.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for fsevents@1.2.4 and node@12.16.1 (node-v72 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables' found at '/'.

No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLILeo' found at '/'.

Comment: No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLI' found at '/'.

gyp: No Xcode or CLT version detected!
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:351:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:311:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 19.4.0